# Translation of HTML content in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-translate

I am using the following Google Sheets formula to translate some fields containing HTML tags:

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(A2, "en", "de")
```

However, the translation results in a messed up HTML and extra spaces between tags opening or closing, especially if there are many nested tags.

For example:

```
<div> <p>paragraph text</p> </div>
```

will result in:

```
<div> <p> Absatztext </ P> </ Div>
```

Sometimes, the translator changes the tags opening and closing and put extra spaces between some attributes also the closing tags letters are in uppercase.

Issues like:

```
<p> Absatztext <P />

<a href = " # "> Link </ A>
```

Sometimes, text are added before the tag closing

```
<h2 Was> ist Pilates? </h2> 
it should be:
<h2> Was ist Pilates? </h2>
```

[image]

Demo here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11MOZjTknFGdwuAp6g3VUa0o5OQaW44hxN2uEvqnL3jw/edit?usp=sharing

How can I fix those problems?

Comment: Just for clarification: is the expected/desired output  " Absatztext"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove HTML In Google Sheets Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660822/remove-html-in-google-sheets-cells)

Comment: @TedinozI don't want to remove the html, I want to keep it with without it being messed up. The translator changes the tags opening and closing and some times put extra spaces between some attributes.

Answer (score 0):

try simple fix like:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(GOOGLETRANSLATE(A1, "en", "de"), "/ ", "/"))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,  TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "</?\S+[^<>]*>", )), 
 GOOGLETRANSLATE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "</?\S+[^<>]*>", )), "EN", "DE"))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is not only in the spaces. The html content is messed up. Some text are put inside the tags closings. I updated the question to let you see more details about the issue I am facing.

Comment: thanks for your time, but it seems that some problems can't be fixed, like the text misplaced inside the tag closing brackets: 
Sometimes, text are added before the tag closing

    <h2 Was> ist Pilates? </h2>

Comment: @Amr are you sure? with 2nd formula from the answer this cant happen

Comment: No it doesn't even translate. Here is the link of the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11MOZjTknFGdwuAp6g3VUa0o5OQaW44hxN2uEvqnL3jw/edit?usp=sharing
 I tried your formula in the third column.

Comment: well there are two issues - its not between tags eg. <tag>text<tag>text<tag> (it should be: <tag>text<tag>) and the 2nd issue is that there is no space between those two sentences so GT wont translate it correctly - https://i.stack.imgur.com/crlAZ.png

Comment: It is a div with many nested tags. It fails when there is many tags. Your answers seems to be removing the html tags. I want to keep them, but only translate their text content. Google always mess the html tags if they have many nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing it in a single formula and just want to solve the problem, you could try splitting it and only translating what's not an HTML tag.

Put all HTML tags and closing tags in a separate sheet, so you can check for them. I'll put mine in 'tags'!A1:B128.

Considering you have your original text in A1, you can split it up by < and >:

```
=SPLIT(A1,"<>")
```

then on a line below (or elsewhere, for me it'll be A2) you can check if the first word in each cell is found among the tags with:

```
NOT(COUNTIF(tags!$A$1:$B$128,INDEX(SPLIT(A2," "),1,1)))
```

translate it if it's true with
`GOOGLETRANSLATE(A2, "en", "de")`
or add the brackets back with
 `"<"&A2&">"` so the whole formula will look like

```
=IF(NOT(COUNTIF(tags!$A$1:$B$128,INDEX(SPLIT(A2," "),1,1))),GOOGLETRANSLATE(A2, "en", "de"), "<"&A2&">")
```

then on a line below, just join the whole row back to a single cell with

```
=JOIN("",A3:L3)
```

You can hide rows 2 and 3 for convenience, or even put them on a separate sheet along with the tags. You can also add a condition not to add < and > if it's empty, so you can join up the whole row without looking at how long it is.

If you'd like to do this in a single formula, you'd have to write a script for it, as some formulas act strangely with arrayformula and sometimes are barely usable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most most convenient solution nowerdays is to use a custom JS-Function (Extensions >> AppScripts):

```
var spanish = LanguageApp.translate('This is a <strong>test</strong>',
                                  'en', 'es', {contentType: 'html'});

// The code will generate "Esta es una <strong>prueba</strong>".
```

`LanguageApp.translate` ([apidoc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language/language-app)) accepts as fourth option a contentType, which can be `text` or `html`.
For huge tables be aware that there are daily limits ([quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas))!

Answer (score 0):

@Fraank got me on the right track, thanks!

Here's how you can set this up an use.

Create a new script by going to Extensions>App scripts in the Google sheet toolbar.

Then use this function:

```
function customTranslate(input) {
  var slovenian = LanguageApp.translate(input, "sr", "sl", {contentType: 'html'});
  return slovenian;
}
```

When you go back to sheet you can now write this formula where you want translation to appear and add target cell on the brackets:

```
=customTranslate(E11)
```