# Remove all HTML tags from a cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I'm trying to remove all the HTML tags and comments within the following cell in Google Sheets:

```
<div class="prod-desc" itemprop="description">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">


<p>This is a 100 count box of the ACC-DX01A Proximity Card to be used with any of our DX line of Access Control Readers. It is the size of a credit card so it can easily fit into your wallet. Use these like a proximity card and carry them on your key ring for easy access. </p>
<p> Please note: To add a DX Card or FOB to the DX Access Control System, you must use the Auto/Add Function. If you need assistance, FREE US based tech support is just a phone call away. </p>

                        </div>
                        <!-- Description Side Bar START   ************************************ -->
                        <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="/images_templ/Accesss-Control_product-image.jpg"> <span class="boxtitle ">Full Line of Access Control</span> <span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: inherit; font-weight: 400">Access Control Proximity Card Readers and Electronic Door Locks and more!</span> </div>
                        <!-- Description Side Bar END   ************************************ -->
                </div>
        </div>
```

So ideally the input should come out as:

```
This is a 100 count box of the ACC-DX01A Proximity Card to be used with any of our DX line of Access Control Readers. It is the size of a credit card so it can easily fit into your wallet. Use these like a proximity card and carry them on your key ring for easy access.
Please note: To add a DX Card or FOB to the DX Access Control System, you must use the Auto/Add Function. If you need assistance, FREE US based tech support is just a phone call away.

Full Line of Access Control Access Control Proximity Card Readers and Electronic Door Locks and more!
```

I've searched around found several answers, however, none of them seems to be working for me, maybe it's because of the new lines and carriage returns? I don't know. What I want to do is remove all the HTML and keep all the newlines and carriage returns in the text. Here are some posts that I was following:

[Remove HTML In Google Sheets Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660822/remove-html-in-google-sheets-cells)

https://superuser.com/questions/564727/html-tags-in-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Looks to me like the first link you sent contains your answer, the proposed regex in there appears to do the trick... how exactly is this different than your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "</?\S+[^<>]*>", ), CHAR(10)))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Besides the answer that @player0 gave, you can also use 'Search and Replace' `ctrl+H`  And then just paste all you wish to change/remove and replace it with nothing. It works for more than 1 cell too.

Its more laborious but you can target the entire book or ranges if needed.